# "1 new answer" on two lines and tabs missing

Tags: bug, design, tabs, new-answers

Often, when I'm reading a new question, I get a banner:

[image]

I click the banner to read the answer, and get this screen:

[image]

The banner with the number of answers appears on two lines. Also, I don't get the tabs `active` `oldest` `votes`. These normally appear in the bar even when there is only one answer, but not when there are none.

When I refresh the page, I get the correct banner with the tabs:

[image]

### Update:

I now get this banner when I click the banner:

[image]

All it says is `1`. It does not say `answer` anywhere.